# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' error when adding SafeAreaView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used the following commands to create a react app:

```
npm install react-native
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

The I added the following line of code in the `App.js` and reloaded the browser.

`import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';`

But it keeps showing the error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/sdan/Documents/Projects/my-app/src'
```

Comment: Try re-running `npm install react-native` **after** creating the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using react not react-native if you want to create and run react-native just flow document https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup and then you can create react-native app like that:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```